# I need to change the calculations for the y-axis. So, how can I customize this axis using the mapboxgl js API?

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I need to change the Y axis in tiles URL. I used following function to change the axis,

```
map.addCustomSource('foo', {
    "type": "vector",
    "tiles": function(coord) {
      return "some computation using coord";
    }
})
```

but it's throwing a `map.addCustomSource is not a function` error.
How can I customize this axis using the Mapboxgl.js API?

Comment: Where are you defining the `map` variable? Please add more code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends how exactly you want to transform the tile coordinates, if it's to match the OGC TMS Spec you can use `"scheme": "tms"` see https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#sources-raster-scheme